# run OpenGL program with double-click in Linux

Tags: c++, linux

I have compiled an C++ program with g++ on Linux. The program works with OpenGL, so I don't need any console output. I just need it to run with a double-click from the user, but when trying to do this, I get:

```
Could not display "/home/jeanc/myprogram/myprogram.bin".
The file is of an unknown type
```

When I run `file myprogram.bin`, I get:

```
myprogram.bin: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, not stripped
```

I also tried giving it execution permission, but I did not work.

Any advice?

Comment: Does it work if you run it from the console like this: `./myprogram.bin`?

Comment: Yes, running ./myprogram.bin from a console works fine

Comment: Which file manager do you use and what does your file manager show when you right-click on the file and select properties?

Comment: Executable programs in Linux doesn't need any special extension. Copy it to just "myprogram" and try with that file.

Comment: I am using Nautilus 2.32.2.1 on Ubuntu 11.10. When seeing the properties, I get: program (application/octet-stream)

Comment: OMG, I feel stupid. @JoachimPileborg you were totally right, it just worked. Sorry

Comment: @joachim: Why would it work without an extension but not *with* an extension (I thought extensions wouldn't matter at all) o.O I don't get it

Comment: I though the same @NiklasB. Never thinked on just deleting the extension

Comment: @NiklasB. The extension matters since Linux tries to associate the extension with an installed program. That's why there was the error `The file is of an unknown type` When you remove the extension (or change it to .out ), the file is considered to be an executable .

Comment: @amal: My file manager doesn't consider extensions at all, it looks at the file's content (magic bytes etc.)

Comment: @NiklasB. Most file managers use the extension to match files with file types. "bin" is probably matched to something else, and not considered an program.

Comment: @NiklasB. What flavor of Linux do you use? In Debian, .out is the extension to indicate an executable (or no extension at all). The file manger (Nautilus) uses extensions to map files.

Comment: @amal: From the Nautilus docs: "The file manager checks the contents of a file to determine the type of a file. If the first lines do not determine the type of the file, then the file manager checks the file extension." -> The first lines of an ELF file certainly determine its file type, thus the extension should never even be looked at.

Comment: @NiklasB. Hmm, it seems to work that way in the command line mode. In the GUI mode, files seem to be associated with their extensions. For eg, changing the extension from .bin to .mp3 opens the file using vlc etc.

Answer (score 3):

What happens when you double-click on a file is entirely the domain of the file manager you're using. I'd check its settings to see if it's been told that .bin files should be opened with another program rather than executed.

Comment: Linux file managers usually don't consider the file extension

Comment: Some of them do, or are at least capable of it.